# Why doesn't the Vampire City character sheet have "Hubris" or "Dark Gifts" traits?

Tags: character-creation, character-sheets, vampire-city

I'm trying to create a character for Vampire City but the [character sheet](http://www.vagrantworkshop.com/files/vampire_city_sheets.pdf) doesn't have room for "Hubris" nor "Dark Gifts", which you have to define on Steps Five and Six.

"Hubris" is the character flaw, that can be played against him for drama. "Dark Gifts" are the vampiric powers. Both are explained in the book, but doesn't appear on the character sheet. And I'd say that as Hubris importance could be debatable, dark gifts are essential.

I attach a couple of images illustrating the point.

This is from the index of Vampire City, on Predator and Prey (character creation) chapter, as found on DriveThruRPG preview.

[image: vampire city index]

And this is a screenshot of the character sheet linked before:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a question about designer intent, which we don't handle here, as the invite too much speculation. Since none of us (that I know of) are designers for this game, we can't know the specific reason that such a key trait was left off of the character sheet. Oversight? On purpose? What was the purpose? Unfortunately, we'll probably never know.

Comment: I fully agree with @RevenantBacon; rephrasing or asking adjacent question might be more relevant – while question for designer intent is unanswerable, you might have a better luck asking about rules, e.g. "how to define hubris for your character and where t write it down" or "how do I keep track of my dark gift" (I know nothing about this ruleset, so excuse potential mishandling of the concepts)